# Проверка длины строки при вводе scanf

Tags: c++, c, проверка, scanf, strlen

Подскажите как проверить длину строки при использовании функции scanf.

```
printf_s("Ведите строку: ");
    scanf_s("%s",&a->author,30);
    fseek(stdin, 0, 0);

    int s = strlen(a->author);
    
    while (s >29)
    {
        std::cout << s;
        printf("Неверное полученное значение, попробуйте еще: ");
        scanf_s("%s", &a->author,30);
    }
```

Comment: Посмотрите на формат `%n` в [scanf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fscanf.3p.html). Если вызвать `int p1, p2; сhar s[LINE_MAX]; scanf("%n%s%n", &p1, s, &p2);`, то количество символов, помещенных в `s[]` (без терминирующего нуля) будет равно `p2 - p1`

Comment: Небольшое дополнение. Формат должен выглядеть так -- **`" %n%s%n"`** (обратите внимание **на пробел** перед первым `%n`)

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что мне нужно будет создать структуру с полями int p1, p2; сhar s[LINE_MAX]?

Comment: Как вам удобней (я же не знаю всего алгоритма обработки). Обычно достаточно просто переменных

Comment: Если Вам нужно ограничить вводимую строку то можно указать `"%30s"`  размер строки 30 символов. Так же строку можно ограничить количеством вводимых символов и какие можно использовать символы `"%30[A-Za-z0-9]"`

Comment: А в чем, собственно, вопрос? Ваш код решает ту проблему, которую вы описали